# Installing gdal-config on my linux

Tags: gdal

I search the entire net could not find a guide to get `gdal-config`.

I have yum but yum does not have `gdal-config`, i already installed `gdal`.

I just need to be able to do this on shell - `gdal-config` and not get a command not found error.

My distro is Fedora. I don't have `apt-get`.

Answer (score 20):

You probaby have "yum" instead of "apt-get" on Fedora.  Try..

```
yum install gdal gdal-devel
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, so I use apt-get instead of Yum.  But I had trouble with gdal and gdal-develop.  This is command that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
```

I found the package names from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdal

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, that is "gdal-config" was missing. I could solve it by installing the development packages. So you could try installing **gdal-dev**.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the GDAL utilities, including gdal-config, are part of the download package that you can find here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries. They link to a Fedora version. If you installed apt-get, you could find it by looking for GDAL directly.