Docker Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
I am trying to create a docker container of a flask server.
I get this error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch~=2.2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch~=2.2.2

those are my files:

requirements.txt

passlib~=1.7.4
pymongo~=3.10.1
Flask~=3.0.2
jsonschema~=4.19.2
torch~=2.2.2
torchvision~=0.17.2
pandas~=2.1.4
pyproj~=3.6.1
fiona~=1.9.5
geopandas~=0.14.3
pillow~=10.2.0
fonttools~=4.51.0
pytest~=7.4.4


Dockerfile

# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.12.0-alpine
LABEL authors="Daniel Ben-Avi, Dean Avram"

WORKDIR /wastewise

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

please help me

There is no Torch wheel for the platform you're on:
FROM python:3.12.0-alpine

Alpine Linux uses musl libc C standard library, not the more common glibc, and that means you can't use the regular manylinux wheels that most packages, Pytorch included, use.
To fix this, use the regular (glibc-backed) Python container:
FROM python:3.12.0

In general, Alpine is not a great choice for Python.

thanks for the fast answer. tried this and I got the next error   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [3 lines of output]
:86: DeprecationWarning: The 'warn' function is deprecated, use 'warning' instead
WARNING:root:Failed to get options via gdal-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
CRITICAL:root:A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
[end of output]

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237223/51685
